# fsproj files in dotnet-core projects

Tags: f#, .net-core

When creating new projects with .net-core (`dotnet new -l F#`), the projects are created with a project.json file and no fsproj file. However, it is my understanding that an fsproj file is needed in order to get intellisense.

**Are there any tools for generating an fsproj file from a project.json file?**

*I am interested in a solution that works both in Linux and Visual Studio as I use both equally for fsharp.*

Answer (score 4):

If you open project.json in Visual Studio 2015 with update 3, it will create an xproj file for the project.

I'm not aware of a way of doing this in linux.

However, as far as I know you don't need an fsproj file to get intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

I found [projekt](https://github.com/fsprojects/Projekt) useful for creating and manipulating `.fsproj` files. However, it will not automatically convert your `project.json` for you.